# Pushed changes is not reflecting in git repository

Tags: git

I pushed my code to git repository, and it is showing in commit list also. But when I see the that file history/changes, it is showing previous day changes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which branch did you push to?

Comment: same branch - leads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was TFS issue.
One of my Team member pushed the merge changes and it was not reflecting in my profile of TFS.
The merged changes was seen by "ADMIN" only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I am unable to ask for clarification due to my reputation points, however, have you tried:

```
    git push origin HEAD:master
```

if this does not work, you can also try through a reset HEAD:

```
    git reset HEAD~1
    git pull
    add/commit/push
```